# How to select only enabled options of a select box using jquery ?

Tags: jquery, select, multi-select

I want to select all options expect the disabled options of a multi select box using jquery. Here is my code,

HTML

```
<select id="agents" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Mango</option>
   <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Apple</option>
   <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Banana</option>
   <option value="4">Guava</option>
   <option value="5">Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all_agent">
<label>Select All</label>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#select_all_agent').on('click', function () {
if($("#select_all_agent").is(':checked')){
    $('#agents option').prop('selected', true);
  }
  else{
      $('#agents option').prop('selected', false);
  }
});
```

When clicking on select all check box it select both enabled and disabled options. How can I select only enabled items ?

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/Leg5qy9b/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:enabled` selector to achieve this. You can also remove the `if` statement by simply setting the property to the state of the checkbox. You should also use the `change` event of the checkbox to enable this functionality for people who browse the using the keyboard.

```
$('#select_all_agent').on('change', function() {
    $('#agents option:enabled').prop('selected', this.checked);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Leg5qy9b/1/)

Comment: ...or use `:enabled` instead of `:not(:disabled)`. Doh! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this**

```
 $('option:not([disabled])').prop('selected', this.checked);
```

[DEMO1 FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/Leg5qy9b/4/)

**OR**

```
$('#agents option').not( "[disabled]" ).prop('selected', this.checked)
```

[DEMO2 FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/Leg5qy9b/3/)

The [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements.The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Comment: Try that with dynamically-enabled/disabled elements cross-browser. It *may* work, but I'm not sure it does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is great. I was trying that.